# Not able to call a controller action in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rspec

I have been trying to implement an RSpec for a Controller called "Estimate controller" to test whether my mailing functionality (sending estimate) working properly or not. But I'm not able to call the controller action from my RSpec. I need to set some values (to, subject, message, cc, current_user, attachments) in a hash and send that hash to Estimate controller.Here is what I tried..

estimates_controller_spec.rb

```
    describe "post 'send_estimate'" do
          it "should send estimate " do
              @estimate = Fabricate(:estimate, id:  Faker::Number.number(10), validity: "12/12/2014", total_value: 1222.00, user_id:@user.id, project_id: @project_id)
est_params = {
          to: "rspec@rails.com",
          subject: "Estimate",
          message: "Check out the Estiamte details",
          cc: "respec@rails.com",
          current_user: @user,
          attachments: ""
        }
           expect{
      post :send_estimate, estimate: est_params
      }.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)

      end 
    end
```

estimates_controller.rb

```
def send_estimate 
    respond_to do |format|
      if @estimate.send_email(params[:to], params[:subject], params[:message], params[:cc], current_user, params[:attachments])
        @estimate.create_activity :send_estimate, owner: current_user, recipient: @estimate.project
        format.html  { redirect_to lead_path(@estimate.project), notice: "Email sent Successfully"}        
        format.json { head :no_content, status: :ok}
      else
        format.json { render json: @estimate.errors }
        format.html { redirect_to contacts_path, notice: 'Something went wrong' }
      end      
    end       
  end
```

Comment: any chance that you forgot to include `spec_helper` / `rails_helper` at the top of your file? Can you test other methods in the controller class from RSpec?

Comment: What error/problem are you getting?

Comment: I have included spec_helper / rails_helper. My output:

EstimatesController post 'send_estimate' should send estimate 

     Failure/Error:

            expect{

       post :send_estimate, estimate: est_params

       }.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)

     

       expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0

     # ./spec/controllers/estimates_controller_spec.rb:85:in `block (3 

levels) in <top (required)>

Comment: You can look at the log/test.log file or attach a debugger like pry into the controller action to see if your parameters are all going in fine and if anything goes wrong.